# Caching in Node Express: How do you whitelist/blacklist views?

Tags: caching, node.js, express

Express has a builtin cache mechanism, [set up](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) with app.enable('view cache'). But how do you discriminate between views which should be cached and views which should always be served fresh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the details, but I think it caches everything. What I mean is that it puts all views inside memory. I don't think you should discriminate between views and should just cache all views. If you don't want this, you could just do the caching yourself by putting them in memory or Redis or something.

But I would advice you to fill issue at [Github](https://github.com/visionmedia/express). I bet TJ will response to that at Github, but does not read this, because at Github he gets email and Stackoverflow he does not.

Comment: TJ confirmed they're all cached.

Comment: Haha that's what I assumed :). All those templates should not consume that much memory :)...

Comment: Also TJ responded pretty quickly over at Github :)

Answer (score 0):

Views which are *mutable* should not be cached; only views which are *static* should be cached.  It's up to your application to determine which is which.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you declare something as mutable? The docs only talk about "static", but it's in the context of raw files in a "public"/"static" directory. Maybe because I'm not running in production (?), but I'm not seeing any such files being generated from views. The views are just dynamically rendered.